# Basic App Crashing When Implementing Images Fade-In

Tags: java, android, crash, imageview, fadein

I'm attempting to work on a simple first Android app, and while eventually it will be a shake-to-activate app, right now it still works with the click of a button because I need to be able to test it on the emulator I have.

The end goal for the app is to, when the device is shaken, choose one random number out of three (each corresponds to a Character from a show) and read that number to fade in an image of that character. Directly after, it fades in a random quote from an array of quotes from that specific character.

Currently, I'd gotten the app working to the point where, when I clicked the button, the app chose a character, and a quote from the array for that character, and was able to fade the quote in. In trying to implement the image fading in, I've done something that makes the app crash when I try to run it.

I'm sure it'll be some stupid mistake, but it would be fantastic if it could be found.

The project has four class files: **MainActivity.java**, DoctorWho.java, **Nine.java**, **Ten.java**, and **Eleven.java**. Nine, Ten, and Eleven are all nearly identical, just using different quotes.

In trying to add the image fade-in, I added it to **DoctorWho.java**, here:

```
public class DoctorWho {

private Nine mNine = new Nine();
private Ten mTen = new Ten();
private Eleven mEleven = new Eleven();
private ImageView mImageView1;
private ImageView mImageView2;
private ImageView mImageView3;

int randomNumber = 0;

public String getDoctorQuote() {
    String quote = "";

    // Choose a Random number out of three values
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);

    // Use that value to choose which of the Doctors to get a quote from
    if (randomNumber == 0) {
        // Quote from Nine
        quote = mNine.getQuote();
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 1) {
        // Quote from Ten
        quote = mTen.getQuote();
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 2) {
        // Quote from Eleven
        quote = mEleven.getQuote();
    }
    else {
        quote = "Error";
    }
    return quote;
}

public void animateDoctor() {
    if (randomNumber == 0) {
        animateNinthDoctor();
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 1) {
        animateTenthDoctor();
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 2) {
        animateEleventhDoctor();
    }
}

private void animateNinthDoctor() {
    AlphaAnimation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1500);
    fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    mImageView1.setAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
}

private void animateTenthDoctor() {
    AlphaAnimation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1500);
    fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    mImageView2.setAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
}

private void animateEleventhDoctor() {
    AlphaAnimation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1500);
    fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    mImageView3.setAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
}
```

In my **MainActivity.java** file, I try to run the animation on-click here:

```
            @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String quote = mDoctorWho.getDoctorQuote();
            mDoctorWho.animateDoctor();
            // mQuoteLabel is the TextView where the quotes are displayed
            mQuoteLabel.setText(quote);
            animateQuoteIn();   
        }
```

The app still starts up fine, and no errors are shown before I run it on the emulator. When I click on the button that should run this sequence, the app crashes. There are no errors shown in the console, and I wasn't able to find a specific line in the LogCat view - I may be looking in the wrong place though. Let me know if updating the post with more code would be helpful in finding what is causing the crash.

Comment: where r u setting mImageView1,mImageView2,mImageView3?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you DoctorWho class as following:

Also have you initialized mImageView1,mImageView2,mImageView3 inside DoctorWho class???

```
public class DoctorWho {

private Nine mNine = new Nine();
private Ten mTen = new Ten();
private Eleven mEleven = new Eleven();
private ImageView mImageView1;
private ImageView mImageView2;
private ImageView mImageView3;

int randomNumber = 0;

public String getDoctorQuote() {
    String quote = "";

    // Choose a Random number out of three values
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);//<--- don't create new randonNumber 

    // Use that value to choose which of the Doctors to get a quote from
    if (randomNumber == 0) {
        // Quote from Nine
        quote = mNine.getQuote();
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 1) {
        // Quote from Ten
        quote = mTen.getQuote();
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 2) {
        // Quote from Eleven
        quote = mEleven.getQuote();
    }
    else {
        quote = "Error";
    }
    return quote;
}

public void animateDoctor() {
    ImageView imageView=null;
    if (randomNumber == 0) {
        imageView=mImageView1;
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 1) {
         imageView=mImageView2;
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 2) {
         imageView=mImageView3;
    }

    AlphaAnimation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1500);
    fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    imageView.setAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
}

}
```